# How to set the proxy of anaconda on (linux) ubuntu16.04

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, proxy, anaconda

I am configuring the anaconda on ubuntu 16.04.
When I use `conda update --all`, there is a error shown as following

> Fetching package metadata ...
>   CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2
>   Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
>   HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>   ProxyError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary >failure in name resolution',)))",),)

Maybe a new proxy setting is necessary on anaconda,however,the ubuntu 16.04 has setted proxy.

I see online that I should add a proxy into a .condarc file that contains the proxy address. Unfortunately,

1. I can not locate the .condarc file on ubuntu 16.04
2. Or there is another way to solve the error?

Any help appreciated Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

create a new file `~/.condarc` in your home directory

```
$ nano ~/.condarc
```

Add these lines below to .condarc file

```
proxy_servers:
    http: http://user:pass@corp.com:8080
    https: https://user:pass@corp.com:8080
```

If your password contains special characters, you need to escape them as described in [Percent-encoding reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters), on Wikipedia.
Sometimes conda commands don't work after these additions due to some bug posted in their repo. If that so removes the .condarc file and try using these commands

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@corp.com:8080
$ export HTTPS_PROXY=https: https://user:pass@corp.com:8080
```

This method sometimes doesn't work but still worth a shot.
Hope this helps. For any queries reach out in the comment section.